# Burnination Request - Invisible

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[invisible](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/invisible) is absolutely useless! Top three questions mean 3 completely different uses.

I suggest getting rid of it.

Comment: Why you want to delete this tag? Is useful to find invisible questions, you know, they are hard to find being invisible and all :/

Comment: Cause in my old age, I can't see stuff that's too small, let alone invisible

Comment: Invisible dragons, they hard to see at night.

Comment: @oliver this is [meta-tag:status-completed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, with no answer, people don't support this... Just ignore the +18 votes above...

Comment: +1 to ignore the +18 ;)

Comment: You posted this question before the proposal for the new cleanup process was even settled. So you might have been experiencing an unusual delay. ;)